# What is the most secure way to upload a file receiving from browser(client)?

Tags: http, file-upload, go, server

I am writing a web app using Golang, and I am writing the file upload part now, but I don't know what is the most secure way to do it.

Can anyone give me some information? Thanks.

**Edit:** I mean how to prevent users upload their file to the position other than the position I want. User may modify the filename to cause it to be uploaded to a specific directory. Are there any way to prevent it?

And I want to ask if the hacking technique like web shell workable to the web app written in Golang? I think is not, but I want to check if my thinking is right.

Comment: Secure in what way? Make sure no man in the middle tempers with the data? The uploader can upload anonymously? Etc. pp. Or Are you afraid of DDoS attacks against your server? Malicious data? You must provide much more details.

Comment: I have updated the content.

Comment: the position is controlled by server side, not client side, at least.

Answer (score 2):

Your server receives a file (e.g. via a form post), and your server code is responsible to save it to a folder of the **server's** choice.

The client has no control over where the server will save it. The client *may* arbitrarily recommend a folder e.g. with another form field (or a subfolder relative to some agreed or arbitrary root), but the client is not in a position to enforce anything.

One thing you should be aware of that if you acquire the posted file name at server side, you should not use it as is, because the client may send a file name which contains folder separators (e.g. `'/'` and it may contain sequences to denote parent folders (e.g. `"../.."`).

What you should do (**most secure**) is to generate a name at the server side. Or if you want to use the name recommended by the client, only use the last part of the sent file name (in case it contains folder names too). Also if you use the name sent by the client, you should check if file already exists to prevent independent clients to overwrite each other's files. Or best would be to use a folder name unique to the client, that way there is no chance to overwrite each other's files.

You may use the [`path`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/) package to check/manipulate file names and paths. For example [`path.Base()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/#Base) returns only the last part (the file name) of a path. And you may use [`path.Join()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/#Join) to concatenate folders and file name.

For example if a client uploads a file via a form post, you may handle it at server side like this:

```
func fileHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    f, fh, err := r.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        // File not submitted? Handle error 
        http.Error(w, "You must upload a file", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    // Save it:
    // Here I use username as a unique client identifier
    saveName := path.Join("path/to/uploaded/files/", username, path.Base(fh.Filename))
    savef, err := os.Create(saveName)
    if err != nil {
        // Failed to create file on server, handle err
        http.Error(w, "Failed to save file", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    defer savef.Close()

    io.Copy(savef, f)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "File saved successfully.")
}
```